# Facebook + Android: Saving a score to user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering how to make a request call and use the GraphAPI to save a user's new highscore score to their account (without having to publish on their timeline).

I had a look at the developer docs however I'm still unsure how to use HttpMethods to 'POST' a score

```
public Request(Session session, String graphPath, Bundle parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook sample app "Friends Smash" contains an example of how to post a score:

https://github.com/fbsamples/android-friend-smash-v2/blob/master/friendsmash_complete/src/com/facebook/android/friendsmash/HomeFragment.java#L1209

Have a look at the tutorial as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial#savescores